# if two consecutive copies of a curve do not intersect, can we add an infinite sequence?

Tags: plane-curves

Start with a simple non-self intersecting curve on the plane from point $A$ to $B$. Then add a translated copy of that curve next to it, so they from a new curve, and assume that also the new curve does not self-intersect.

My question is: if I iterate this indefinitely, can intersections appear (given the first and second copy did not intersect)?

This is certainly not true in 3D space. I can make a curve and concatenate three copies, so that the first and second (and the second and third) copy do not intersect, but the first and third one do.

[image]

Comment: Can we not do the same in 2D, even using circular segments?  Eventually the circle closes back on itself.

Comment: @hardmath The curve segments are just translations of the first one, starting where the previous copy stopped.

Comment: I'd like to see your 3D example.  Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy like this?

Comment: It seems it ought to be possible to prove that if the $n$th copy intersects any earlier copy then it also intersects the $(n-1)$th and therefore the first copy intersects the original.

Comment: @HendrikJan I'm not able to visualize your example, but thanks for trying. Cheers!